# is there an easier way to validate field length on an input field in Salesforce Screen Flow, or do I need to add custom validation each time?

Tags: screen-flow

It seems like screen flow should have a max length setting for text fields, but it does not.  Does this mean for every text field I need to add custom validation to check the length?  I feel like Salesforce could have done this better, so I'm wondering if maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a validation formula on the input field itself. E.g. if the field is a text input named My_Text, and you want it 12 or fewer characters long, use:

```
LEN({My_Text}) <= 12
```

While this seems a faff, it is very flexible since you can have all sorts of scenarios, like the input must be between 4 and 12 characters long, or it must be 3 **or** 6 characters long etc. etc.